# How to instal SSL certificate to my website

Tags: asp.net, ssl-certificate

I am very new to https and SSL certificates, I have asked my Host Provider to put SSL certificate for my websites, they asked me to download two files and instal on my website. My projects are Asp.net MVC.

my question is how I should install them? or at least should I or not? I expect everything must be automatically

Appreciate any help

Comment: It depends on your hosting provider's control panel. They have their own customised versions of control panels from where they can give you the option to import the certificate. You should better check your provider's knowledge base or raise a support ticket with them.

Comment: what are the files? Whether the site is written in MVC or not is irrelevant, by the way. HTTPS is transport layer security. The content being transmitted, and the means of creation of the content, plays no part in the configuration of HTTPS. Frankly I'm very surprised the hosting company doesn't handle this for you automatically, that's pretty shoddy service. At the very least they should be giving you precise instructions of what to do, if they force you to do it yourself.

Comment: @ADyson two files with .crt and .p7b suffix

Comment: @BalajiBirajdar thank you for your great idea

Comment: are you on a shared host or your own VPS? if you have your own private server, perhaps you have to install it yourself. I assume you're using IIS, if so then google "install .crt file IIS" and you can find generic guides to get you started. Make sure you find one for your particular IIS version. I would also still contact the host provider and ask them if they have specific guidance or support available as well.

Comment: @ADyson thank you very much, it is a shared host. usefull info. appreciate

Comment: No problem. If it's a shared host then as Balaji said I'd really expect it to be done via your control panel's GUI interface. That said, I've never used a hosting company who didn't just install them in an automated fashion when requested to do so.

Comment: @ADyson As your help, it solved. feel free to answer this question , I would accept to help others. goodluck

Comment: @ADyson You can move your comment to the answers section

Comment: Well, thankyou, but I don't actually know which one of my various suggestions turned out to be the correct solution in this case? You mentioned that the problem was solved but didn't say exactly how.